# Getting different answers using different methods in a geometrical problem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Problem statement: *Given a triangle with side lengths 4 and 6, their corresponding opposite angles have a 1:2 ratio. Find the length of the third side.*

I solved the problem in 2 ways and got as an answer {5} on one of them and {4; 5} on the other. Can someone explain to me what's going on?
[image: First way]

[image: Second way]

Comment: The second solution is the direct way of using the cosine law to find the POSITIVE value a side. The first one is an indirect (or even can be thought of as an improper) way of using the cosine law. This is because an extraneous root has been generated from the quadratic. Further testing (like @mathlove ‘s work) is needed to find out which one (4 or 5) is the invalid value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two ways is how to use the rules of cosines. You may want to check if each solution is sufficient.

Suppose that $BC=4$. Let $D$ be the midpoint of the side $AB$. Since $\angle{BCD}=\angle{DBC}=x$, one has to have $BD=CD$. However, this does not hold because $$BD=6/2=3,\ \ \ CD=\sqrt{3^2+4^2}=5.$$
This is a contradiction. Hence, $BC\not =4$.

Comment: That's a great contradiction. Could you, please, get further explaining how the ways of using the cosines rule differ? My point of view is that I'm using thorems and basic algebraic operations and for some reason I get different results using different ways. Can you make it clear to me why that happens? What's the thing that make one have a {5} and the other {4; 5}?

Comment: @user1113314: In the first, you used $AC^2=BA^2+\color{red}{BC}^2-2\cdot BA\cdot \color{red}{BC}\cdot\cos{\angle{ABC}}$. In the second, you used $\color{red}{BC}^2=AB^2+AC^2-2\cdot AB\cdot AC\cdot\cos{\angle{BAC}}$. See also Mick's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The sine rule has ambiguous case . See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines#The_ambiguous_case.